# How do I fold text in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I feel like an idiot not even posting some code, but after reading several articles stating iOS7 Text Kit adds support for Text Folding, I can't actually find any sample code or an attribute to set on the text to fold it and Apple's documentation seems mute on it.

http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/220 makes me think I set a region of text into its own text container and then display/hide it, perhaps by overriding setTextContainer:forGlyphRange:

Am I anywhere close?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There's a WWDC 2013 video that talks a bit about it when they're doing custom text truncation. Basically you implement the NSLayoutManagerDelegate method `layoutManager: shouldGenerateGlyphs: properties: characterIndexes: font: forGlyphRange:`
It took me way too much struggling to actually come up with code for this, but here's my implementation based on a property `hideNotes`

```
-(NSUInteger)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager shouldGenerateGlyphs:(const CGGlyph *)glyphs
      properties:(const NSGlyphProperty *)props characterIndexes:(const NSUInteger *)charIndexes
            font:(UIFont *)aFont forGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphRange {

    if (self.hideNotes) {
        NSGlyphProperty *properties = malloc(sizeof(NSGlyphProperty) * glyphRange.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < glyphRange.length; i++) {
            NSUInteger glyphIndex = glyphRange.location + i;
            NSDictionary *charAttributes = [_textStorage attributesAtIndex:glyphIndex effectiveRange:NULL];
            if ([[charAttributes objectForKey:CSNoteAttribute] isEqualToNumber:@YES]) {
                properties[i] = NSGlyphPropertyNull;
            } else {
                properties[i] = props[i];
            }
        }
        [layoutManager setGlyphs:glyphs properties:properties characterIndexes:charIndexes font:aFont forGlyphRange:glyphRange];
        return glyphRange.length;
    }

    [layoutManager setGlyphs:glyphs properties:props characterIndexes:charIndexes font:aFont forGlyphRange:glyphRange];
    return glyphRange.length;
}
```

The NSLayoutManager method `setGlyphs: properties: characterIndexes: font: forGlyphRange:` is called in the default implementation and basically does all of the work. The return value is the number of glyphs to actually generate, returning 0 tells the layout manager to do its default implementation so I just return the length of the glyph range it passes in. The main part of the method goes through all of the characters in the text storage and if it has a certain attribute, sets the associated property to NSGlyphPropertyNull which tells the layout manager to not display it, otherwise it just sets the property to whatever was passed in for it.

Comment: I don't have a better way, but isn't there a danger of attributesAtIndex: not giving you the expected value if glyphs don't map 1:1 with characters?

Comment: To avoid a mismatch between the glyphs and character index, I think the glyphIndex should be "charIndexes[i]" instead of "glyphRange.location + i". Also glyphIndex could be better renamed to characterIndex.